# Prevent inserting an empty memo

Tags: delphi

I am checking the contents of the memo before an insert query.

```
if memo1.lines.Text = '' then begin
showmessage('Warning:Missing data!');
abort;
end else ....
```

It works ok as long as there is nothing in the memo1.
However, when user hits enter inside the empty memo and the cursor moves
to the second line,running the query, fires the insert without a warning message,
though theres nothing in the memo.
Is there a way to prevent this ?

Comment: Pardon my curiousity, but does what is in the memo get written to a db field and, if it does, why not use a TDBMemo?

Comment: @MartynA Databound controls are a big no-no for lot of people. Most of them keeps an open transaction to the database which is highly ill-advised in most of the cases.

Comment: @mg30rg Good point.  I'm so used to doing things the 3-tier/CDS way that I'd overlooked that.  Mind you, I was under the impression from an earlier q that the OP was using DBX or FD, which is pretty much the same thing, in terms of isolating the client from server processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the user hits enter your memo's text contains whitespace (the line-return), and so it doesn't equal ''.

You need to Trim the Text first. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.Trim

```
var
    memoText : String;
```

...

```
memoText := Trim(memo1.lines.Text);
if memoText = '' then 
begin
    showmessage('Warning:Missing data!');
    abort;
end else ....
```

Comment: This won't work.  Trim() only removes leading and trailing spaces from a string.  It will not remove the CR/LF that will separate multiple lines (even blank ones) in a TStrings list.

Comment: Ignore above comment - Trim() does indeed remove all non-printing characters.  My bad.

Comment: This is massively inefficient when memo has lots of text

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What is it about the implementation of Trim() that causes it to be "massively inefficient" for larger n? I would expect running time to be tied to the amount of leading and trailing whitespace, and not the length of the string itself.

Comment: The use of Text is the issue. Even so, trimming a huge string is not cheap either.

Comment: ahh. That makes some sense. Assuming we absolutely need all lines in a single String, is there really anyway to avoid this? It makes sense to avoid superfluous calls to Text.

Comment: You don't need all lines in a single string.

Comment: I would be reluctant to optimize at the expense of readability unless this was proven to be a real issue. I'm not convinced, so I'd definitely be interested in some metrics, or further runtime analysis.

Comment: @trooper I agree. Unless this function was called very frequently it's likely no issue. I just baulk at the idea of concatenating every line of a potentially huge amount of text just to discover that the first character was not whitespace. That feels wrong to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan _"You don't need all lines in a single string."_ So you are saying that iterating trough memo1.Lines.Strings to see if they contain any text would be faster? (I'm not sure its not, but lazy to write a framework test. :v)

Comment: @mg30rg The fast way to do this is to avoid the heap alloc and the memory copy and iterate through the buffer provided by `EM_GETHANDLE`. Iterating through the `TStrings` is surely quite slow. Reading `Text` is not as bad as perhaps I'm making out, because the underlying control does at least store the data in a single contiguous buffer and so all that is involved is a single heap alloc and a memory copy.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Thanks. But wouldn't it lead to ugly and unreadable code? (Unless you organise the whole shebang into a separate method but then calling it involves an extra stack operation.)

Comment: @mg30rg It could easily enough be wrapped up I think, but everyone is right when saying that such an optimisation is likely premature. Perhaps I should just have kept my mouth shut!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't really think such optimization is necessary but I like to learn about that so shutting your mouth would be a loss to me.

Comment: FWIW - Memo.Text is an extremely thin and really quite efficient wrapper around WM_GETTEXT - it does not involve assembling a string from constituent lines or any such shenanigans.  Using EM_GETHANDLE to access the content buffer more directly may be more efficient but certainly also more cumbersome given the hoops required to be jumped through in order to use that content buffer safely, and those hoops may negate at least some of the performance gains otherwise obtained.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I have looked into the VCL sources and found that `TMemo.GetText()` is not the same or referring to `TMemo.Lines.GetText()` but referring to `TControl.GetText()`, so Deltics is right.

Comment: @mg30rg I know. That's what I was getting it in my last but one comment in this thread when I said, *Reading Text is not as bad as perhaps I'm making out, because the underlying control does at least store the data in a single contiguous buffer and so all that is involved is a single heap alloc and a memory copy.*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Sorry then. I thought that `TMemo.GetText()` is the same as `TMemo.Lines.GetText()` and my impression was you are thinking the same. (I'm not native in English and sometimes I partially miss the information compacted into a short comment. I thought you are referring to reading text the WinAPI way and not reading the `.Text` property.)

Answer (score 1):

If the user pressing RETURN is resulting in an additional line in the memo, then you must have the **WantReturns** property set to **TRUE**, and an **OnKeyPress** or **OnKeyDown** event handling the #13 key or **VK_RETURN** virtual key code.

If you set **WantReturns** to FALSE then the user must use *CTRL+ENTER* to insert a new line, and a simple striking of the RETURN key will **not** insert an empty line.

But if you are happy with the way your user interface currently behaves and simply want to check whether or not the memo contains only whitespace then you will have to validate this separately using **Trim(Memo.Text)** or some other mechanism for testing the content of the memo to meet your applications definition of "not empty".

As others have noted, using **Trim()** on **Memo.Text** simply in order to test for the presence of non-whitespace characters is potentially very inefficient, though how much of a concern this is in your case will depended a great deal on the expected content of the memo in your application.

A more efficient way to test for a non-whitespace string would be:

```
function ContainsOnlyWhitespace(const aString: String): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := FALSE;

  for i := 1 to Length(aString) do
    if (aString[i] > ' ') then
      EXIT;

  result := TRUE;
end;
```

Which would be used thus:

```
if ContainsOnlyWhitespace(Memo.Text) then
begin
  // show warning message etc...
end;
```

This will be significantly more efficient than **Trim()** since it does not involve producing any new strings or modifying the string being tested.

Comment: *"CR/LF pair which will not be removed"* That's incorrect, please see documentation of Trim.

Comment: Interesting... What version of Delphi are you working with Deltics?

Comment: Oops, you're right, Trim() does remove all non-printing characters.  My bad.

Comment: The function in your original answer is likely more efficient than Trim(Memo.Text)

Comment: Possibly, but there is an even more efficient technique that could be employed which I'll add to my answer.

Comment: @Deltics Also your solution would not work with a string containing only spaces.

Comment: ContainsOnlyWhitespace() would return TRUE for a string containing only spaces, which I think would be the expected result, no ?